# Magento2 With Redis, Error: MySQL adapter: Missing required configuration option 'host' (Sometimes)

Tags: mysql, docker, redis, magento2

I have configured Magento2.3.4 on docker(windows 10 using docker toolbox). Then I added another service "redis" into my docker-compose file and started using redis for backend cache and page cache in Magento2.3.4. I'm getting "MySQL adapter: Missing required configuration option 'host'" sometimes not always. Even frontend working but not backend. I teardown all docker containers and removed all docker volumes, build fresh from the docker compose file and now not able to setup upgrade. I debug a little and found that anyhow Magento is trying to connect to MySql multiple times and in the last attempt database configuration is empty (but in env.php) it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here; solved by adding 'host', 'dbname', 'username' and 'password' in *db > connection > indexer* with same data as *db > connection > default* in app/etc/env.php file